# Brezis-Nirenberg type problem

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes

I am interested the following variation of the Brezis-Nirenberg problem:

$$ -\Delta u(x) = (1+g(x)) u(x)^p  \quad \mbox{ in } \quad \Omega$$
with $u=0$ on $ \partial \Omega$.  Here $\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $ \mathbb{R}^N$ with smooth boundary and where $g(x) \ge 0$ is continuous and bounded and $ p:=\frac{N+2}{N-2}$.

My question is whether equation has been studied; in particular whether people have shown the existence of a positive solution under suitable conditions on $g(x)$.

Any comments would be greatly appreciated. 
greg

Answer (score 1):

In a [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02582916) by Wang Xu-jia your problem is analyzed in a even more general way.

(FTR: I can't comment yet..)

Comment: oh impressive find... never heard of this paper (and it looks like its never been cited...which seems weird).   After looking at the paper I am not sure whether it covers my situation; so if your familiar with it maybe you happen to just know the answer.  Suppose $ \Omega=B_1(0)$ (unit ball at origin) and suppose $g(r)$ is increasing (with extra conditions or parameters if needed).  Do this paper show the existence of a positive solution?    Thanks for your comments

Comment: There are some results regarding functions like $g(r)$, but I didn't study the paper in depth.